# Why didn't Harry Potter and Dumbledore create Horcruxes to battle Lord Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Dumbledore and Harry were well aware of the fact that Voldemort used Horcrux spells to come back from death. They also knew they would need an army of magicians to fight him.

Why didn't they use Horcruxes to increase the chances of their survival, and instead relied on their single lives and risk everything when they knew "cheat codes" for the game?

Also, I would like to ask: If Harry had used Horcrux spells, would Voldemort's soul be further divided into the number of Horcruxes Harry created?

Comment: You should probably split your second question out into a separate one

Comment: Having rolled back my revision, I'm forced to vote to close as unclear. You're asking two distinct questions

Comment: @Valorum I am asking two related question in one post so that I can get answer's in one post. It's ok if you get offended by it and decide to downvote that's your right but that's my point of view.

Comment: @Ishan - I'm not in the least bit offended. I am, however concerned that you're asking two separate and distinct question; "Why didn't Harry/Dumbledore create horcruxes" and "What would have happened if Harry had tried to split his soul". They're related but they're not the same

Comment: @Ishan - if it requires two different answers, it's two different questions.  Unfortunately, this site is community moderated, which means the community will decide whether your question is appropriate, and you don't seem to be making the best of impressions.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131650/4918 "Did Dumbledore make a horcrux?"

Comment: Dumbledore makes reference to Riddle 'using horcruxes' whilst he used 'hallows' - can't find the exact references though

Comment: This question has to be closed as "too broad" since you're asking two distinct questions. (It's already been closed for a year, but I just changed the close reason from "unclear" to "too broad" after a community flag.) There's a recent related question whose answers you might find interesting: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/204153/31394

Answer (score 6):

Because one needs to commit something really ugly to create a horcrux. Such as to kill someone. Neither Harry, nor Dumbledore would do that, even to defeat Voldemort.

From book 6, chapter "Horcruxes", the real Slughorn memory

> [Tom Riddle] “How do you split your soul?”
>
> “Well,” said Slughorn uncomfortably, “you must understand that the soul is supposed to remain intact and whole. Splitting it is an act of violation, it is against nature.”
>
> “But how do you do it?”
>
> “**By an act of evil — the supreme act of evil**. By committing murder. Killing rips the soul apart. The wizard intent upon creating a Horcrux would use the damage to his advantage: He would encase the torn portion —”
> ....

Comment: If Harry had used Horcrux spells, would Voldemort's soul be further divided into the number of Horcrux Harry created?

Comment: It is a difficult matter of speculation. It could possibly: 
divide;
be destroyed;
move to another object, thus leaving Harry's body;
interfere with the Horcrux creation process, killing Harry

Comment: @Ishan  Doesn't Voldemort's soul attach to Harry's physical form, rather than his "soul"? If that's the case, I don't think splitting Harry's soul would have any effect on Voldemort's soul fragment, since they wouldn't be splitting the Horcrux.

Comment: Harry could have used Horcrux spell if he had killed Nagini the snake or any other wizard who were with Voldemort.

Comment: @ishan No, killing is not enough - see the quote in answer. You must commit murder.

Comment: @Ishan - self defense isn't the same thing as murder, and there's no evidence that anyone (except maybe Hermione) studied the spell at all enough to cast it, or would have had time to in the middle of the Hogwarts battle.

Comment: @Radhil - Also, killing a snake isn't considered murder.